# Ruby Check one element in a list array against another element in the same array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm sure theres a simple solution to this but I'm stuck at iterating over an array of words and comparing the first word (eventually its length) against every word in the list and then checking the second against them all and the third and so forth.

if I had two options I could do something like this

```
word1 = "weird"
word2 = "wired"

if word1.chars.sort.length == word2.chars.sort.length
  true
else
  false
end
```

im starting simple.

EDIT

having these words I would check whether they are anagrams.

I have a text file with thousands of words. So 
the out put would be something similar to this

```
There were 17346 anagram words found.
Would you like to list them? (Y/n)> Y
...
weird wider wierd wired wried
weirs wires wiser wries
```

EDIT 2

I want to write a program that will find all of the anagrams http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagram in a wordlist. For example, the words "silent" and "listen" are anagrams.

imagine a dictionary there are many anagrams there, but they are not in order, or related, they have the same elements but different positions, the program would be satisfied with reading from the word.txt file and finding the anagrams words, I'd have the number of anagrams found, and a choice of displaying my findings. with a sample like this

```
...
weird wider wierd wired wried
weirs wires wiser wries
welkin winkle
welkins winkles
welting winglet
weltings winglets
wenchers wrenches
wettish whitest
whale wheal
```

something like this.

words = %q(welting winglets with white whit withe wised wield wides ...)

the iteration would from welting to winglets check if they're anagram
if so perhaps store in a new array or something. then go to with check it, and so on.

Comment: sorry does that clarify a little bit? @muistooshort

Comment: I still don't understand.  You show us how to tell if two words are anagrams of each other, but it's not clear what you want to do with that.  I think a small sample of the input list, and the output that it would generate, would help a lot.

Comment: So the idea is to find words with the same elements(letters) within the file, and be able to display them if the user choses to. It is required to display the numbers of findings tho. My issue is doing some sort of  nested loop which was my first approach to accomplish all that. @WayneConrad

Comment: Considering that, `word.chars.sort.length == word.chars.length == word.length`, I don't know why you don't just use the last one.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want all the anagrams, you could do...

```
words.group_by{|w| w.split('').sort}.values
```

That will give you an array of arrays, each of which will be all words in the list that are anagrams of each other.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to do, but if you need to look at all the words with the same length, then this might help:

```
> words = %w[cat dog fish bird red blue green white pink]
=> ["cat", "dog", "fish", "bird", "red", "blue", "green", "white", "pink"]

> words.group_by{|e| e.length}
=> {3=>["cat", "dog", "red"], 
    4=>["fish", "bird", "blue", "pink"], 
    5=>["green", "white"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

if your array is this: `words = ["wierd", "wired", "wierd", "vafasdfasd"]`

You would compare the first word to every word like this:

```
for i in 0...words.length
    if words[0] == words[i]
        puts true
    else
        puts false
    end
end
```

But to repeat this for each other word in the array you need to use a nested loop. This could work

```
for i in 0...words.length
    for j in i...words.length
        if words[i] == words[j]
            puts true
        else
            puts false
        end
    end
end
```

Assuming that a word is not an anagram of itself:

```
for i in 0...words.length
    for j in i...words.length
        if words[i] == words[j]
            puts false
        elsif words[i].chars.sort == words[j].chars.sort
            puts true
        else
            puts false
        end
    end
end
```

By the way, I would imagine that the above would not be considered good code. If you were comparing anagrams fine, but you might be comparing things that you could have doubles of (but still don't want to compare things to themselves). This would be a better solution I think:

```
for i in 0...(words.length-1)
    for j in i...(words.length-1)
        if words[i].chars.sort == words[j+1].chars.sort && words[i] != words[j+1]
            puts true
        else
            puts false
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Yea this was my first approach, but still it didn't quite get there with my solution, I tried it with a nest .each I'm not sure comparing with the same words is the way to go, the challenge is to find words that are anagrams, have the same letters/elements but different positioning, but the approach seems correct, i just have to work the logic to make it word now =)

Comment: you could always discount words that were exactly equal? (see correction)

Comment: I've added my 2-cents worth as well. (Just saying, but it would be complete amazing if this was my first accepted answer on stack overflow :) :) :) )

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Phillip, it's not clear exactly what you are looking for, but here is another guess at what you are trying to do.

```
reference_word = "12345"

my_array = %w(weird wired not_wierd not_wired)

my_array.select { |item| item.length == reference_word.length }
        .each { |matched_size| puts matched_size }
```

replace the `{ |matched_size| puts matched_size }` with whatever you want to do with the items that match the size of your reference word

Answer (score 0):

If your question stems from a hunch that it might be faster to filter on word length, you could that by modifying @SteveTurczyn's answer thus:

```
words = %w{wierd a wired ow dew wierd vafasdfasd wed wo}
  #=> ["wierd", "a", "wired", "ow", "dew", "wierd", "vafasdfasd", "wed", "wo"] 

words.group_by { |w| w.length }.values.flat_map do |a|
  if (a.size > 1)
    a.group_by{|w| w.split('').sort}.values
  else
    [a]
  end
end
  #=> [["wierd", "wired", "wierd"], ["a"], ["ow", "wo"],
  #    ["dew", "wed"], ["vafasdfasd"]]
```

The steps:

```
h = words.group_by { |w| w.length }
  #=> {5=>["wierd", "wired", "wierd"], 1=>["a"], 2=>["ow", "wo"],
  #    3=>["dew", "wed"], 10=>["vafasdfasd"]} 
b = h.values
  #=> [["wierd", "wired", "wierd"], ["a"], ["ow", "wo"],
  #    ["dew", "wed"], ["vafasdfasd"]] 
b.flat_map do |a|
  if (a.size > 1)
    a.group_by{|w| w.split('').sort}.values
  else
    [a]
  end
end
  #=> [["wierd", "wired", "wierd"], ["a"], ["ow", "wo"],
  #    ["dew", "wed"], ["vafasdfasd"]]
```

The first element of `b` passed into the above block by `flat_map`, and assigned to the block variable `a`, is:

```
a = ["wierd", "wired", "wierd"]
```

We therefore perform the operation:

```
if (3 > 1)
  ["wierd", "wired", "wierd"].group_by{|w| w.split('').sort}.values
else
  [["wierd", "wired", "wierd"]]
end
```

Since `3 > 1` is `true`:

```
c = ["wierd", "wired", "wierd"].group_by { |w| w.split('').sort }
  #=> {["d", "e", "i", "r", "w"]=>["wierd", "wired", "wierd"]}
d = c.values
  #=> [["wierd", "wired", "wierd"]]
```

Since we using `flat_map`, rather than `map`, `a` is mapped to the array `["wierd", "wired", "wierd"]`.

The other elements of `b` are processed similarly.